# How to get all source files that make up a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

For a fairly complex Visual Studio 2013 solution consisting of many large C++ projects, how can I get the paths to *all* my source code files that end up in my executable for a specific target platform / architecture? This should include the source code from all my projects the application transitively depends on. Example:

```
Solution
|
+-- Project: Application (depends on "Library A")
|   |
|   + File: defs.h
|   |
|   + File: main.cpp
|
+-- Project: Library A (depends on "Library B")
|   |
|   + File: libA.h
|   |
|   + File: libA.cpp
|
+-- Project: Library B
    |
    + File: libB.h
    |
    + File: libB.cpp
```

In the above, suppose `Application` depends on `Library A`, and `Library A` depends on `Library B`. When inspecting the `Application` project, what I'm looking for is the list of paths to the files `defs.h`, `main.cpp`, `libA.h`, `libA.cpp`, `libB.h`, `libB.cpp`.

I'm looking to rely as much as possible on information that is provided by the build tools, like the exact command line that gets passed to the compiler, or some dependency graph. I do not want to write a script that tries to extract all that information from scratch.

Currently, I'm not interested in dependencies to binary / pre-compiled libraries, but only in the source code files that end up in one way or the other in the final executable.

Comment: Open `.vcxproj` file with text editor. Search for `ClCompile` and `ClInclude`.

Comment: Manually? For hundreds of projects? For which I would again manually need to figure out the project dependencies?

Comment: You can write script, 'cos .vcxproj is simple xml

Comment: Of course I could write a script. My point is that doing it this way the script would become fairly complex. For example, while an `<ItemGroup>`'s `<ClCompile>` tags list the source files, the header files these include are not directly listed. The script would need to parse the source code to get them manually, taking any preprocessor defines into account. I'm more looking for the exact command line that gets passed to the compiled for a specific platform and architecture. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Finding the .cpp files is not particularly hairy, they are listed in the project files.  Finding the #include files is much trickier, it depends on configuration and directory search order.  Use the /showIncludes compile option to get the compiler to report the full path of the file.  Do not assume that this is easy to implement, this is buy and not build.  Something like CppDepend, not an endorsement.